# Data get doubled when i run method in Sequelize Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have model, and in each column you can create children column with postId,
like this
[
{
id: model Id,
parentId: parent id
}
]

And when im running a method of Sequelize findAndCountAll(), im getting a doubled data

This is my model:

````
        id: {type: DataTypes.UUID, primaryKey: true},
        name: DataTypes.STRING(100),
        postId: DataTypes.UUID,
        view: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, defaultValue: 0},
        status: DataTypes.STRING(8),
    },
    {
        paranoid: true,
        deletedAt: "softDelete"
    }
);

Model.hasMany(Model, {
    as: 'children', // Имя ассоциации (может быть любым)
    foreignKey: 'parentId', // Имя поля, содержащего идентификатор родительского элемента
});```

And this is my method:
        ```const models: any = await Model.findAll({
            nest: true,
            order: [['name', 'ASC']],
            include: [
                {
                    model: Model,
                    as: 'children',
                    attributes: {exclude: ['postId', 'createdAt', 'softDelete', 'parentId']},
                },
            ],
            attributes: {
                exclude: ['postId', 'createdAt', 'softDelete', 'parentId'],
            },
            offset: data.offset,
            limit: data.limit,
        });
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.